# Switching values when editing a cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, editing

I have a JTable which uses a custom TableModel to display a series of object instances. There's a switch case inside `getValueAt(int row, int column)` to return values according to given attributes (see below). One return statement involves returning a value of 1/0 as true/false.

Is there a way that I can modify this TableModel so that it displays a 1/0 when a cell is edited?

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    User user = (User)dataVector.get(row);
    switch (column) {
        case ID_INDEX:
           return user.getId();
        case USERNAME_INDEX:
           return user.getUserName();
        case PASSWORD_INDEX:
            return "****";
        case ACTIVATED_INDEX:
            return (user.getActivated())?"true":"false";
        default:
           return new Object();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default renderer and editor for `Boolean`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) is a `JCheckBox`. Consider using

```
case ACTIVATED_INDEX:
    return Boolean.valueOf(user.getActivated());
```

Alternatively,

```
case ACTIVATED_INDEX:
    return (user.getActivated())?"1":"0";
```

Addendum: As an example, [`DefaultTableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) does not override `getColumnClass()`, and `AbstractTableModel` simply returns `Object.class`. Your `TableModel` should override `getColumnClass()` accordingly:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel() {

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
        return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
    }
};
// add some data
JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
```

Comment: Thanks. The TableModel I'm using seems to produce a simple String instead of a JCheckBox. From the link, it appears that the renderer used depends on the result of `getColumnClass()`.

Comment: @James P.: Yes, I've elaborated above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look at [`TableCellRenderer`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) and [`TableCellEditor`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html):

A `TableCellRenderer` is responsible for rendering cell data when it is not being edited, where as a `TableCellEditor` is responsible for providing a component used to edit the value of a cell. You can therefore represent the data in two separate ways depending on whether it is being edited or just rendered as per normal.

You should however consider that if you return a Boolean type from the getValueAt() method, your JTable should automatically render a JCheckBox, when the cell is in edit mode, the JCheckBox value can be changed by clicking on it as usual. To do this just return:

```
case ACTIVATED_INDEX:
    return Boolean.valueOf(user.getActivated());
```

Comment: Links updated and changed to `TableCellRenderer and `TableCellEditor`.