# Sort JTable column of longs

Tags: java, sorting, jtable, long-integer, comparator

I'm trying to sort a column in my JTable.  The column contains Long's (j[ava.util.Long](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Long%29)), which implement Comparable.  Therefore, reading [this document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html), it says:

1: If a Comparator has been specified for the column by the setComparator method, use it.

2: If the column class as returned by getColumnClass is String, use the Comparator returned by Collator.getInstance().

3: If the column class implements Comparable, use a Comparator that invokes the compareTo method.

4: If a TableStringConverter has been specified, use it to convert the values to Strings and then use the Comparator returned by Collator.getInstance().

5: Otherwise use the Comparator returned by Collator.getInstance() on the results from calling toString on the objects.

My code does not create a custom Comparator object, so #1 is out.  The column is a column of Long's so #2 is out.  #3 states that it should sort by the Long "compareTo" method.  But it doesn't.  If my JTable has 3 Longs, 90,900, and 111, it will sort them, "900,90,111" or "111,90,900".  It appears to be sorting them like strings, as stated in #5.

Here is out we create our table:

```
table = new JTable( new CustomTableModel( new Vector<Vector<Object>>() ,Record.getNames() ) );
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

And then adding info:

```
public void setRecords( Iterable<Record> records ){
    CustomTableModel model = (CustomTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    model.clearRecords();

    for( Record r : records ){
        Vector<Object> v = new Vector<Object>();
        v.add(r.getFromNumber());
        v.add(r.getToNumber());
        v.add(r.getStartDate());
        v.add(new Long( r.getDuration() ) );
        model.addRow(v);
        model.addRecord(r);
    }
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(2);
```

How can I fix it, so the last column (column 3), is sorted by Long/long/int, and not by string?  I looked into custom comparators, but I wasn't sure how to implement.  Shouldn't the JTable use #3?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that your model's `getColumnClass()` method returns `Long.class`.

Comment: Ahh, it returns "Object", rather than Long. Where do I set/change that?

Comment: Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305198) using `DefaultTableModel`, and [another](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) using `AbstractTableModel`.

Comment: Excellent; looking closer, the second [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) also `implements Comparable` in order to sort by `Value`.